# Group of Endomorphisms

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Consider an abelian group $G$. I will define a new group $E$ whose elements are the set of all endomorphisms from $G$ to $G$.

The multiplication $*$ in $E$ should be defined like so:

$a*b = c$ where $c:G\rightarrow G$ is the map defined by $c(x) = a(x)+b(x)$

From here it is easy to see $E$ is a group, the identity is the map taking all elements to the identity of $G$. The inverse of a map $a$ is a map $b$ that takes $x$ to $-a(x)$. Also it is easy to verify associativity, thus $E$ is a group.

I would like to know what this group $E$ is called in relation to the group $G$. Is it called the endomorphism group? If not what is its name?

Thanks.

Comment: You should also check that $E$ is closed under the operation, which is not the case in general, unless $G$ is commutative.

Comment: Why does $*$ make sense? WHe do you think that, if $a,b\in E$, then $a*b\in E$ too?

Comment: you are right, it only works for abelian group, I have edited my question accordingly

Comment: ${\rm Hom}(G,G)$.

Comment: There is the notion of the endomorphism ring of an abelian group/module. Your group is the additive part of this endomorphism ring.

Comment: I just discovered that it is indeed called "the endomorphism group of an abelian group" in "Introduction to Abstract Algebra" by Jonathan D. H. Smith, Definition 9.8.